# When is the difference between quotRem and divMod useful?

Tags: haskell, division

From the haskell report:

> The quot, rem, div, and mod class
>   methods satisfy these laws if y is
>   non-zero:
>
> ```
> (x `quot` y)*y + (x `rem` y) == x
> (x `div`  y)*y + (x `mod` y) == x
> ```
>
> `quot` is integer division truncated
>   toward zero, while the result of `div`
>   is truncated toward negative infinity.

For example:

```
Prelude> (-12) `quot` 5
-2
Prelude> (-12) `div` 5
-3
```

What are some examples of where the difference between how the result is truncated matters?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Many languages have a "mod" or "%" operator that gives the remainder after division with truncation towards 0; for example C, C++, and Java, and probably C#, would say:

```
(-11)/5 = -2
(-11)%5 = -1
5*((-11)/5) + (-11)%5 = 5*(-2) + (-1) = -11.
```

Haskell's `quot` and `rem` are intended to imitate this behaviour. I can imagine compatibility with the output of some C program might be desirable in some contrived situation.

Haskell's `div` and `mod`, and subsequently Python's / and %, follow the convention of mathematicians (at least number-theorists) in always truncating *down* division (not towards 0 -- towards negative infinity) so that the remainder is always nonnegative. Thus in Python,

```
(-11)/5 = -3
(-11)%5 = 4
5*((-11)/5) + (-11)%5 = 5*(-3) + 4 = -11.
```

Haskell's `div` and `mod` follow this behaviour.

Comment: "so that the remainder is always nonnegative" Technically, the sign of of `mod` follows the sign of the second operand.

Comment: it's to maintain the property that `(q,r) = divMod x y` if and only if `x = q*y + r`.  Run an example, it's clever how it works out.

Comment: @luqui: No, that does not explain it. You can always have x=q*y+r with r nonnegative; e.g. if `divMod 11 (-5) = (-2, 1)` (instead of (-3,-4)), you'd still have "11 = (-2)*(-5) + 1". So your condition does not force the sign of `mod` to follow the second operand. BTW, the property that `x=q*y+r` is always true of quotRem as well, and there are always infinitely many pairs (q,r) such that `x=q*y+r` (and exactly two of these pairs have |r|<q, except when r=0 gives a solution there's only one pair).

Comment: hmm, yeah.  Maybe `mod` is compensating for some related design decision in `div`?   Not sure...

Comment: Actually, while C99 and C++11 do specify the truncation-to-0 definition, earlier versions left it implementation-defined, so "compatibility with C" is an unlikely (or at least bad…) reason for other languages or programs to go with truncation-to-0.

Comment: But in Python `11 % -5 == -4`, the result is negative. How do you fit your  *" the convention of mathematicians"* for the case when dividend >0 and divisor < 0, and  then `a%b` is `<0`?

Answer (score 28):

This is not exactly an answer to your question, but in GHC on x86, quotRem on Int will compile down to a single machine instruction, whereas divMod does quite a bit more work.  So if you are in a speed-critical section and working on positive numbers only, quotRem is the way to go.

Comment: For solving the SPOJ primes, using rem rather than mod  makes my test file run in 4.758s rather than 5.533s. This is means the quicker version is 16% quicker under 32-bit Ubuntu, Haskell Platform 2011.

Comment: @TimPerry, I don't think that follows. What if you did one `mod` in your whole program and saw that same improvement?

Comment: I stated that when I changed calls in my primes code from mod to rem and I saw a 20% speedup. It is not a theoretical comment. It was a description of an event. I only changed one thing (albeit multiple places) and I saw a 20% speedup. It seems a 20% speedup *DID* follow.

Comment: @TimPerry ah I thought "the quicker version" referred to `rem`, not your modified program.  (Not sure why I thought you wouldn't just say `rem` if that's what you meant though...)

Comment: On many architectures including x86, when dividing by non-constants, using truncate-toward-zero division is slightly faster than than floor-toward-negative-infinity, but when dividing by many constant values, especially powers of two, truncate-toward-zero is much faster (e.g. one instruction versus 3).  I would posit that code which is speed-sensitive is apt to have more "fast" divisions in it than slow ones.

Answer (score 7):

A simple example where it would matter is testing if an integer is even or odd.

```
let buggyOdd x = x `rem` 2 == 1
buggyOdd 1 // True
buggyOdd (-1) // False (wrong!)

let odd x = x `mod` 2 == 1
odd 1 // True
odd (-1) // True
```

Note, of course, you could avoid thinking about these issues by just defining odd in this way:

```
let odd x = x `rem` 2 /= 0
odd 1 // True
odd (-1) // True
```

In general, just remember that, for `y > 0`, `x mod y` always return something `>= 0` while `x rem y` returns 0 or something of the same sign as x.