# Difference between `mod` and `rem` in Haskell

Tags: haskell

What exactly is the difference between `mod` and `rem` in Haskell?

Both seems to give the same results

```
*Main> mod 2 3
2
*Main> rem 2 3
2
*Main> mod 10 5
0
*Main> rem 10 5
0
*Main> mod 1 0
*** Exception: divide by zero
*Main> rem 1 0
*** Exception: divide by zero
*Main> mod 1 (-1)
0
*Main> rem 1 (-1)
0
```

Comment: Don't know Haskell, but it's likely these are the same operation. `mod`ulus == `rem`ainder.

Comment: To be fair, it wasn't the same question. The other question assumed understanding of the answer to this question.

Comment: @Dan Reading that question, because of another question I had (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892188/problems-obtaining-the-list-of-divisors-of-a-number-in-haskell), I realized the same :/

Comment: it's the same difference as between `div` and `quot`

Answer (score 214, accepted):

They're not the same when the second argument is negative:

```
2 `mod` (-3)  ==  -1
2 `rem` (-3)  ==  2
```

Comment: I had the same question about `rem` and `mod` in Clojure, and this was the answer.

Comment: Nor are they the same when the first argument is negative. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8111203/1535283 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/339823/1535283 for some more info about these tricky operations.

Comment: Also from http://stackoverflow.com/a/6964760/205521 it seems like `rem` is fastest.

Comment: Though this answer is correct, an answer claiming no more than "not the same" to a question "what is the difference" is a very bad one. I would welcome it if you could expand on "how" they are different and some usecases probably.

Answer (score 81):

Yes, those functions act differently. As defined in the [official documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html):

`quot` is integer division truncated toward zero

`rem` is integer remainder, satisfying:

```
(x `quot` y)*y + (x `rem` y) == x
```

`div` is integer division truncated toward negative infinity

`mod` is integer modulus, satisfying:

```
(x `div` y)*y + (x `mod` y) == x
```

You can really notice the difference when you use a negative number as second parameter and the result is not zero:

```
5 `mod` 3 == 2
5 `rem` 3 == 2

5 `mod` (-3) == -1
5 `rem` (-3) == 2

(-5) `mod` 3 == 1
(-5) `rem` 3 == -2

(-5) `mod` (-3) == -2
(-5) `rem` (-3) == -2
```

Comment: Your last four examples are probably not what you mean, since `mod` and `rem` associate more strongly than `(-)`. I've edited your comment since I can't seem to put multi line stuff in this comment.

Comment: @ErikHesselink: you introduced an error with your edit. `(-5) \`mod\` 3 == 1`

Comment: @ChengSun Thanks, I've fixed it. Should be live after review.

Answer (score 23):

Practically speaking:

If you know both operands are positive, you should usually use `quot`, `rem`, or `quotRem` for efficiency.

If you don't know both operands are positive, you have to think about what you want the results to look like. You probably don't want `quotRem`, but you might not want `divMod` either. The `` (x `div` y)*y + (x `mod` y) == x `` law is a very good one, but rounding division toward negative infinity (Knuth style division) is often less useful and less efficient than ensuring that `` 0 <= x `mod` y < y `` (Euclidean division).

Answer (score 9):

In case you only want to test for divisibility, you should always use `rem`.

Essentially `` x `mod` y == 0 `` is equivalent to `` x `rem` y == 0 ``, but `rem` is faster than `mod`.

Comment: Why is `rem` fastern them `mod`?

Comment: At least in the case of `Int` and `Integer`, `mod` is implemented in terms of `rem`, but requires some extra checks: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.7.0/docs/src/GHC-Classes.html#modInt%23, http://hackage.haskell.org/package/integer-gmp-1.0.3.0/docs/src/GHC.Integer.Type.html#modInteger

Answer (score 3):

```hs
quotRem' a b = (q, r) where
    q = truncate $ (fromIntegral a / fromIntegral b :: Rational)
    r = a - b * q
divMod'  a b = (q, r) where
    q = floor    $ (fromIntegral a / fromIntegral b :: Rational)
    r = a - b * q
```

ex:

```hs
(-3) / 2 = -1.5
(-3) `quot` 2 = truncate (-1.5) = -1
(-3) `div`  2 = floor    (-1.5) = -2
(-3) `rem` 2 = -3 - 2 * (-1) = -1
(-3) `mod` 2 = -3 - 2 * (-2) = 1

3 / (-2) = -1.5
3 `quot` (-2) = truncate (-1.5) = -1
3 `div`  (-2) = floor    (-1.5) = -2
3 `rem` (-2) = 3 - (-2) * (-1) = 1
3 `mod` (-2) = 3 - (-2) * (-2) = -1
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

This is a graph of haskell's `mod` and `rem` over [-20,20] integer range:

[image]

Comment: That's useful, but the captions are rather confusing and the colours hard to keep apart. Three individual plots and a line of actual Haskell code for each would be much better to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot upload an image to explain it. But you can draw it yourself.

suppose :

```
X = mod(a,b)  ; Y = rem(a,b)

---(-(n+1)b)---a---(-nb)---.......--(-2b)-----(-b)-----0-----b--->

X = a - [ -(n+1)b ]
```

so that X is always positive

```
Y = a - [ -nb ]
```

in standard documentation:

```
mod  -->  a - b.*floor(a./b).......floor is closer to negative infinity

rem  -->  a - b.*fix(a./b).........fix is closer to 0
```