# Problems obtaining the list of divisors of a number in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, floating-point, integer

**This is not a duplicate question**. Read below...

I'm declaring the following function:

```
divisors x = [(a, x/a) | a <- [2..(sqrt x)], x `mod` a == 0]
```

What I want to obtain is the divisors of `x`: A list of tuples that will contain `(n, k)` such as `n * k = x`

**Example:**

```
> divisors x
[(1,10), (2, 5)]
```

Why the above code isn't working?

It gives me the error:

```
*Main> divisors 10

<interactive>:1:0:
    Ambiguous type variable `t' in the constraints:
      `Floating t'
        arising from a use of `divisors' at <interactive>:1:0-10
      `Integral t'
        arising from a use of `divisors' at <interactive>:1:0-10
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

I've tried manually setting the signature of the function without success...

Comment: Which function signatures did you try?

Comment: `(Integral a, Floating a) => ...`, `(Num a) => ...`, with `RealFrac` too,...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. All of them helped a lot, not only to solve the problem, but also to understand what was happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `sqrt` returns a `Floating a`, and you really just want integers when finding divisors. You can turn a `Floating a` into an `Integral a` with `ceiling`, `floor` or `round`. I will use `ceiling`, as I'm not sure if using `floor` or `average` won't skip a divisor.

The sqrt function also only accepts a floating number, so you will have to convert an integer into a floating before giving it to it (this can be done with `fromIntegral`).

Also, you use `/`, which also works with floating numbers. Using `div` is better as it works with integral numbers (rounding when necessary).

```
divisors x = [(a, x `div` a) | a <- [2..(ceiling $ sqrt $ fromIntegral x)], x `mod` a == 0]
```

With this, `divisors 10` will give `[(2,5)]` (your code stops the `(1,10)` case from happening - I'm guessing this was intentional). Unfortunately you will get duplicates, eg `divisors 12` will return `[(2,6),(3,4),(4,3)]`, but that shouldn't be too hard to fix if it is a problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can see the problem if you ask for the type:

```
 divisors :: (Integral t, Floating t) => t -> [(t, t)]
```

and then check what things are both `Integral` and `Floating`:

```
 Prelude> :info Floating
 class Fractional a => Floating a where
 instance Floating Float -- Defined in GHC.Float
 instance Floating Double -- Defined in GHC.Float
```

and

```
 Prelude> :info Integral
 class (Real a, Enum a) => Integral a where
 instance Integral Integer -- Defined in GHC.Real
 instance Integral Int -- Defined in GHC.Real
```

so, it can be neither Int, Integer, Float or Double. You're in trouble...

Thankfully, we can convert between types, so that while `sqrt` needs a Floating, and `mod` needs an Integral (btw, `rem` is faster), we can either, e.g., do away with floating point division:

```
 divisors :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer)]
 divisors x = [(a, x `div` a) | a <- [2..ceiling (sqrt (fromIntegral x))], x `rem` a == 0]

 > divisors 100
 [(2,0),(4,0),(5,0),(10,0)]
```

However, you need to think hard about what you really mean to do when converting integer types to floating point, via `sqrt`...

Comment: Did you change intentionally `(a, x / a)` by **(a, x `rem` a)**?

Comment: Ah yes, to again remove the floating point division. Do you really want floating point divisors?

Comment: `rem` returns the modulus, not the division, doesn't it?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Typo. Fixed. `div`, (not `mod` or `rem`)

Answer (score 3):

In Haskell, integer division and fractional division are different operations, and have different names.  The slash operator, `/`, is for fractional division.  Integer division is accomplished with `div` or `quot` (the difference between the two having to do with the behavior when there are negative numbers involved).

Try replacing `x/a` with

```
x `quot` a
```

instead.

The compiler error tells you exactly this: that you're treating a type sometimes as an integral number (by using `mod`), and sometimes as a fractional number (by using `/`), and it's not sure how to pick a type that acts like both of those.

You'll have a similar issue with `sqrt`, once that's sorted, though.  There again, you need to be consistent about whether your types are integers or (in that case) floating point.  For the purpose of finding possible divisors, it should suffice to range up to the greatest integer less that the floating point, so consider using `floor (sqrt (fromIntegral x)))`.  The `fromIntegral` converts `x` (which must have an integral type) to a different type -- in this case, it will default to `Double`.  The `floor` then converts the `Double` result back into an integral type.

Comment: Alright, so I confused the errors... it's actually complaining about `sqrt` first.  The complaint about `/` will come once `sqrt` is fixed.

Comment: @Oscar: I mentioned a second problem in the edit.  Sorry about the incomplete answer to start.  See if that fixes it.

Comment: Still not working. Here's what I've got so far: `[(a, x ``quot`` a) | a <- [2..(floor(sqrt x))], x ``rem`` a == 0]` (forget about double **`**. I had to type those because it wasn't formating the code correctly

Comment: Okay, and there's yet a third problem, which is the need to convert `x` to a Double or other floating point type prior to calculating a square root, since `x` itself is integral.  Editing the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking the square-root to bound the search, you can allow the comprehension to range over an infinite list, and use `takeWhile` to stop the search when the remainder is greater than the divisor:

```
divisors x = takeWhile (uncurry (<=)) [(a, x `div` a) | a <- [1..], x `mod` a == 0]

> divisors 100
[(1,100),(2,50),(4,25),(5,20),(10,10)]
```

Note: your original example shows `(1,10)` as one of the `divisors` of `10`, so I started the comprehension from `1` instead of `2`.

Hmm, this does search beyond the square-root until it hits the next factor above.

How about this:

```
divisors x = [(a, x `div` a) | a <- takeWhile ((<= x) . (^2)) [1..], x `mod` a == 0]
```