# Integral operators quot vs. div

Tags: haskell

Type class Integral has two operations `quot` and `div`, yet in the Haskell 2010 Language Report it is not specified what they're supposed to do. Assuming that `div` is integral division, what does `quot` differently, or what is the purpose of `quot`? When do you use one, and when the other?

Comment: This seems like a promising link: http://cdsmith.wordpress.com/2007/06/02/learning-number-theory-and-haskell-the-division-algorithm/

Answer (score 120, accepted):

To quote section 6.4.2 from the Haskell report:

The `quot`, `rem`, `div`, and `mod` class methods satisfy these laws if y is non-zero:

```
(x `quot` y)*y + (x `rem` y) == x  
(x `div`  y)*y + (x `mod` y) == x
```

`quot` is integer division truncated toward zero, while the result of `div` is truncated toward negative infinity.

The `div` function is often the more natural one to use, whereas the `quot` function corresponds to the machine instruction on modern machines, so it's somewhat more efficient.

Comment: +1 for the discussion of when you might prefer one over the other

Comment: or, equivalently, the result of `mod` has the same sign as the divisor, while the result of `rem` has the same sign as the dividend

Comment: Thanks for the answer, especially for mentioning the paragraph in the HR. I was looking only in chapter 9.

Comment: I worked this out as an English sentence to help me grok it. I believe this describes the truth for both equations; the variation in meaning is determined by what is meant by "quotient" (i.e. whether using quot or div semantics). Here goes: "The remainder is the difference between the dividend and the product of the quotient and the divisor."

Answer (score 37):

The two behave differently when dealing with negative numbers. Consider:

```
Hugs> (-20) `divMod` 3
(-7,1)
Hugs> (-20) `quotRem` 3
(-6,-2)
```

Here, `-7 * 3 + 1 = -20` and `-6 * 3 + (-2) = -20`, but the two ways give you different answers.

Also, see here: http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html

The definition for `quot` is "integer division truncated toward zero", whereas the definition for `div` is "integer division truncated toward negative infinity".