# Exact difference between div and quot

Tags: haskell, operators, division

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111120/integral-operators-quot-vs-div) question here on SO the differences between the two operators `div` and `quot` are mentioned as well as the fact that the `quot` operator is more efficient than the `div` operator, whereas `div` is more natural for us humans to use.

My question is what the exact implementations of the two operators are and linked to that what the difference between implementations is. Also I want to know how the speed difference between those two comes to be, as using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) and browsing the sources did not help me in my quest to understanding.

I want to clarify that I understand the general difference between the two operators and only am interested in the implementations or rather the differences.

Comment: I added a tiny bit of benchmarking too, FYI.

Comment: As @augustss mentions in his answer to the question you linked, the *fundamental* reason for the speed difference is that `quot` is what is usually implemented directly as an instruction in modern CPUs. Thus, as mentioned below, that is what GHC chooses as its primitive operation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`quot` rounds towards zero, `div` rounds towards negative infinity:

```
div  (-3) 2 == (-2)
quot (-3) 2 == (-1)
```

As to the overhead of `div`, `quot` has a corresponding [primitive GHC operation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.2/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.3.1.0/GHC-Prim.html#g:3), while `div` does [some extra work](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.8.2/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-Base.html):

```
quotRemInt :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
(I# x) `quotRemInt` (I# y) = case x `quotRemInt#` y of
                             (# q, r #) ->
                                 (I# q, I# r)

divModInt# :: Int# -> Int# -> (# Int#, Int# #)
x# `divModInt#` y#
 | (x# ># 0#) && (y# <# 0#) = case (x# -# 1#) `quotRemInt#` y# of
                              (# q, r #) -> (# q -# 1#, r +# y# +# 1# #)
 | (x# <# 0#) && (y# ># 0#) = case (x# +# 1#) `quotRemInt#` y# of
                              (# q, r #) -> (# q -# 1#, r +# y# -# 1# #)
 | otherwise                = x# `quotRemInt#` y#
```

In their final forms, both functions have some [error handling checks on them](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Real.html#div):

```
a `quot` b
 | b == 0                     = divZeroError
 | b == (-1) && a == minBound = overflowError -- Note [Order of tests]
                                              -- in GHC.Int
 | otherwise                  =  a `quotInt` b

a `div` b
 | b == 0                     = divZeroError
 | b == (-1) && a == minBound = overflowError -- Note [Order of tests]
                                              -- in GHC.Int
 | otherwise                  =  a `divInt` b
```

I also did a very small bit of microbenchmarking, but it should be taken with a hefty amount of salt, because GHC and LLVM optimize tight numeric code away like there's no tomorrow. I tried to thwart them, and the results seem to be realistic: **14,67 ms** for `div` and **13,37 ms** for `quot`. Also, it's GHC 7.8.2 with -O2 and -fllvm. Here's the code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Criterion.Main
import System.Random

benchOp :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> ()
benchOp f = go 0 0 where
    go !i !acc !limit | i < limit = go (i + 1) (f i) limit
                      | otherwise = ()

main = do
    limit1 <- randomRIO (1000000, 1000000 :: Int)
    limit2 <- randomRIO (1000000, 1000000 :: Int)
    n      <- randomRIO (100, 100 :: Int)
    defaultMain [
        bench "div"  $ whnf (benchOp (`div`  n)) limit1,
        bench "quot" $ whnf (benchOp (`quot` n)) limit2]
```

Comment: I don't know enough about benchmarking to tell whether your benchmark tests negative numbers. Does it?

Comment: @dfeuer it's all positive. I ran some with negative numbers, and the results were similar, but anyway I think this is not a very good piece of benchmarking; a better one would be where we use NOINLINE-s and look at the GHC Core to make sure we're benchmarking the right thing.

Comment: The reason I mentioned the negatives is that if GHC/LLVM is smart enough to realize there are only positives, then it will gut the `divMod` logic after inlining. You're probably right that more careful benchmarking is needed, but I'm *definitely* not the right one to do that.