# Any way to achieve something like overriding an operator in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Recently I was working with lists in kotlin and had the following snippet:

```
a = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
println(a[-2])
```

Of course this causes an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` so I thought it would be nice to extend this functionality. So I thought one could override the `get` operator in the `List` class:

```
operator fun <T> List<T>.get(index: Int): T =
        // Here this should call the non-overridden version of
        // get. 
        get(index % size)
```

I understand that extensions are just static methods and therefore cannot be overridden, but is there a way one can achieve something like this?

Of course you could just create another function

```
fun <T> List<T>.safeGet(index: Int): T = get(index % size)
```

but I'd like to know if there are other ways.

*(I understand that `index % size` is a very naive way of doing what I want, but it's not the focus of my question and makes the code smaller.)*

**EDIT**

When I wrote this question I thought the `%` operator would return always positive numbers when the right hand side is positive - like in python. I'm keeping the original question here just for consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying something impossible, because extensions are always shadowed by members, even `@JvmName` cannot save you.

Workaround: use your second solution, or add a `Unit` parameter which is ugly (looks like `a[x, Unit]`) but can exist with its own `get` method together.

Another solution: create your own `List` implementation (recommended).

Answer (score 3):

Since `get` operator is already defined in `List`, you cannot redefine `get` (with one `Int` parameter).
However, you can override `invoke` operator, which is not defined in `List`.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
    println(a(-2))
}

// If `index` is negative, `index % size` will be non-positive by the definition of `rem` operator.
operator fun <T> List<T>.invoke(index: Int): T = if (index >= 0) get(index % size) else get((-index) % (-size))
```

although I think that creating a new extension method to `List` with an appropriate name will be more preferable option.

As a sidenote, `(positive value) % (negative value)` is non-negative, and `(negative value) % (positive value)` is non-positive.
`%` in Kotlin corresponds to `rem` in Haskell in the following example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28027235/869330

Comment: ok, the side note caught me out of surprise. I did not expect that. Thanks!