# What does % do in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, modulo

I'm used to using % to mean "modulo" in other languages. In Haskell, we have to use `mod x y` or `` x `mod` y ``. So, what is this symbol used for in Haskell?

Comment: Show an example of its use. I don't remember any uses for it offhand, but it's very possible to make your own definition of it, so libraries may define it.

Comment: it's in `Data.Ratio`, see here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Ratio.html#v:-37- (Unless of course there is another definition of `%` in another library, as is entirely possible.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Haskell, we can define binary operators with various symbols (including `%`) like ordinary functions, So you can define `%` as an arbitrary operator you want (in the module which you define it).

As the most typical case, `%` is provided as the constructor of the `Ratio` type by [Data.Ratio module](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.8/base-4.12.0.0/Data-Ratio.html).

Try the code below on GHCi to make sure that `%` is provided by `Data.Ratio`:

```
ghci> 3 % 9

<interactive>:1:3: error:
    Variable not in scope: (%) :: Integer -> Integer -> t
ghci> import Data.Ratio
ghci> 3 % 9
1 % 3
```

And remember you can search such operators and functions in these search engines:

- https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/
- https://www.stackage.org/

Actually I've looked up how `%` is defined by [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%25).

% is an infix function defined as

```
(%) :: Integral a => a -> a -> Ratio a
```

and from the type definition above, you can see that it is part of the `Data.Ratio` library, which mostly deals with ratios (i.e.: fractions). Its code is

```
x % y = reduce (x * signum y) (abs y)
```

thus given two integrals (x,y) , it returns an irreducible fraction x/y

Answer (score 11):

With a quick look on [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%25), you can see that `%` is an infix function defined as

```
(%) :: Integral a => a -> a -> Ratio a
```

and as you can guess it is part of the `Data.Ratio` library, which mostly deals with ratios (i.e.: fractions). It is code is

```
x % y = reduce (x * signum y) (abs y)
```

thus given two integrals (x,y) , it returns an irreducible fraction x/y

Comment: Never heard of Hoogle. I am new to Haskell. I searched via DDGo, and not one article mentioned Data.Ratio. This resource was not included in general search results. See: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=operator+haskell&t=ffab&atb=v155-6&ia=software

Comment: Is there a way to look up those type definitions for Data.Ratio in GHCi/Prelude? I already tried `:t %` to no avail

Comment: @Ryan, Hoogle at https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ is a search engine for Haskell libraries. you can reach it at that link and you can then search for any function, some function description and -- the most important -- function types. As I said, `%` is part of the `Data.Ratio` library, so before you can use it in the GHCi -- including `:t`, you need to import it by `import Data.Ratio`. Then you can see the type. Remember also you can use `:info` that sometimes gives you more info than just `:t`

Answer (score 2):

[Searching for `(%)` on Stackage Hoogle](https://www.stackage.org/lts-13.8/hoogle?q=(%25)), it appears that `Data.Ratio` defines the `%` operator as constructing a `Ratio` value from a numerator and denominator. A GHCi example:

```
Prelude> :m + Data.Ratio
Prelude Data.Ratio> let x = 1 % 2
Prelude Data.Ratio> x
1 % 2
Prelude Data.Ratio> :t x
x :: Integral a => Ratio a
```

Answer (score 1):

`Data.Ratio` uses `%` as a constructor, but unless that type was defined before the `Integral` type class, it doesn't explain why `%` was *available* for use by `Data.Ratio`. (Of course, qualified imports allow you to use the same operator name in multiple modules, so either way, `%` being used by `Data.Ratio` isn't really a reason.)

Note, however, that `Integral` defines [both `mod` and `rem` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891140/difference-between-mod-and-rem-in-haskell). I suspect that `%` was intentionally left out of `Integral`, both to avoid 1) making a choice as to whether it should be an alias for `mod` or `rem`, as well as 2) making people remember which choice was made.

Also, [languages use different definitions for `%`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1907565/c-and-python-different-behaviour-of-the-modulo-operation), so either `(%) = mod` or `(%) = rem` had the potential for confusing *someone*.

Comment: There's also a nice version (I think maybe in Python?) that guarantees a positive result regardless of the signs of the operands, as well as guaranteeing `q * n + r = m`.

Comment: Python `%` is Haskell `mod`, I believe.

Comment: Huh. Got that wrong. R6RS Scheme's `mod` does it "Euclidean style", as does PureScript (which used to do it Knuth style but switched).

Answer (score 1):

Found this in "Old School" Davies *Introduction to Functional Programming Systems Using Haskell*. (He constantly compares Haskell to Pascal.) It's a simulation of stack arithmetic

```
type Stack = [Float]

push :: Float -> Stack -> Stack
push x stack = x : stack

addStack :: Stack -> Stack
addStack (x:y:stack) = (y + x) : stack

subtStack :: Stack -> Stack
subtStack (x:y:stack) = (y - x) : stack

multStack :: Stack -> Stack
multStack  (x:y:stack) = (y * x) : stack

divStack :: Stack -> Stack
divStack  (x:y:stack) = (y / x) : stack

emptyStack :: Stack
emptyStack = []

popStack :: Stack -> (Float, Stack)
popStack (top:rest) = (top,rest)
```

Then

```
let f % g     = g . f
    actionsOn = push 12.2 %
                push 7.1 %
                push 6.7 %
                divStack %
                push 4.3 %
                subtStack %
                multStack %
                push 2.2 %
                addStack
in popStack (actionsOn emptyStack)

(-37.331642,[])
```

This is just a neater version of a crazy-looking nested function

```
popStack (addStack (push 2.2 (multStack (subtStack (push 4.3 (divStack (push 6.7 (push 7.1 (push 12.2 emptyStack)))))))))
```

which itself avoids creating and passing a new stack for each stack operation. In summary, what YAMAMOTO Yuji says right at the beginning is applicable here and not really any `Ratio` stuff AFAIK.