# Can I speed up this Haskell algorithm?

Tags: haskell

I've got this haskell file, compiled with `ghc -O2` (ghc 7.4.1), and takes 1.65 sec on my machine

```
import Data.Bits
main = do
    print $ length $ filter (\i -> i .&. (shift 1 (i `mod` 4)) /= 0) [0..123456789]
```

The same algorithm in C, compiled with `gcc -O2` (gcc 4.6.3), runs in 0.18 sec.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    int count = 0;
    const int max = 123456789;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < max; ++i)
        if ((i & (1 << i % 4)) != 0)
            ++count;
    printf("count: %d\n", count);
}
```

**Update**
I thought it might be the `Data.Bits` stuff going slow, but surprisingly if I remove the shifting and just do a straight `mod`, it actually runs *slower* at 5.6 seconds!?!

```
import Data.Bits
main = do
    print $ length $ filter (\i -> (i `mod` 4) /= 0) [0..123456789]
```

whereas the equivalent C runs slightly faster at 0.16 sec:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    int count = 0;
    const int max = 123456789;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < max; ++i)
        if ((i % 4) != 0)
            ++count;
    printf("count: %d\n", count);
}
```

Comment: Haskell equivalent of `%` is `rem`, not `mod`. The latter has extra checks for negative numbers, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339719

Comment: This is trivial enough that you could check the difference in the generated assembly :) ? I don't have a Haskell compiler on this machine, so I can't check it for you.. Seems Vitus is onto something.

Comment: changing to `rem` made about a 10% difference; 1.45s and 4.9s now for the respective problems.

Comment: Does it help if you replace `[0..123456789]` with `([0..123456789] :: [Int])`? Just wondering whether you get some unfortunate `Num` instance deduced (such as `Integer`).

Comment: @MortenJensen the C assembly is 45 lines and the Haskell is 2086!

Comment: In your second version, the list returned by `filter` contains three times as many elements as in the first. I guess that's why it takes three times as long to run - the slow part is probably building the list.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe That sped up the 2nd calculation nearly 4*, down to 1.17s, but didn't seem to affect the first calculation.  They're still way slower than C though.

Comment: FWIW, compiling with `-O2 -fllvm -funfolding-use-threshold1000` makes it go fast (about the same as C) for me. (Edit: actually not, only "faster" -- I made some other changes in between that make it go as fast as C.)

Comment: This code looks like it can be fused into a loop, but when I look at the core output, the call of `filter` generates a list.  That is probably why ghc is slower.

Comment: @Heatsink: This won't fuse because [`length` is not a "good consumer"](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/876).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The two pieces of code do very different things.

```
import Data.Bits
main = do
    print $ length $ filter (\i -> i .&. (shift 1 (i `mod` 4)) /= 0) [0..123456789]
```

creates a list of 123456790 **`Integer`** (lazily), takes the remainder modulo 4 of each (involving first a check whether the `Integer` is small enough to wrap a raw machine integer, then after the division a sign-check, since `mod` returns non-negative results only - though in ghc-7.6.1, there is a primop for that, so it's not as much of a brake to use `mod` as it was before), shifts the `Integer` 1 left the appropriate number of bits, which involves a conversion to "big" `Integer`s and a call to GMP, takes the bitwise and with `i` - yet another call to GMP - and checks whether the result is 0, which causes another call to GMP or a conversion to small integer, not sure what GHC does here. Then, if the result is nonzero, a new list cell is created where that `Integer` is put in, and consumed by `length`. That's a **lot** of work done, most of which unnecessarily complicated due to the defaulting of unspecified number types to `Integer`.

The C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int count = 0;
    const int max = 123456789;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < max; ++i)
        if ((i & (1 << i % 4)) != 0)
            ++count;
    printf("count: %d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

(I took the liberty of fixing the return type of `main`), does much much less. It takes an **`int`**, compares it to another, if smaller, takes the bitwise and of the first `int` with 3<sup>(1)</sup>, shifts the `int` 1 to the left the appropriate number of bits, takes the bitwise and of that and the first `int`, and if nonzero increments another `int`, then increments the first. Those are all machine ops, working on raw machine types.

If we translate that code to Haskell,

```
module Main (main) where

import Data.Bits

maxNum :: Int
maxNum = 123456789

loop :: Int -> Int -> Int
loop acc i
    | i < maxNum = loop (if i .&. (1 `shiftL` (i .&. 3)) /= 0 then acc + 1 else acc) (i+1)
    | otherwise  = acc

main :: IO ()
main = print $ loop 0 0
```

we get a much closer result:

```
C, gcc -O3:
count: 30864196

real    0m0.180s
user    0m0.178s
sys     0m0.001s

Haskell, ghc -O2:
30864196

real    0m0.247s
user    0m0.243s
sys     0m0.003s

Haskell, ghc -O2 -fllvm:
30864196

real    0m0.144s
user    0m0.140s
sys     0m0.003s
```

GHC's native code generator isn't a particularly good loop optimiser, so using the llvm backend makes a big difference here, but even the native code generator doesn't do too badly.

Okay, I have done the optimisation of replacing a modulus calculation with a power-of-two modulus with a bitwise and by hand, GHC's native code generator doesn't do that (yet), so with ```rem``` 4`` instead of ```.&. 3`, the native code generator produces code that takes (here) 1.42 seconds to run, but the llvm backend does that optimisation, and produces the same code as with the hand-made optimisation.

Now, let us turn to [gspr's question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12731688/1011995)

> While LLVM didn't have a massive effect on the original code, it really did on the modified (I'd love to learn why...).

Well, the original code used <del>`Integer`s and</del> lists, llvm doesn't know too well what to do with these, it can't transform that code into loops. The modified code uses `Int`s and the `vector` package rewrites the code to loops, so llvm *does* know how to optimise that well, and that shows.

<sup>(1)</sup> Assuming a normal binary computer. That optimisation is done by ordinary C compilers even without any optimisation flag, except on the very rare platforms where a `div` instruction is faster than a shift.

Comment: Thanks for having a go at my question (and writing a great and lengthy answer in general!), but I must admit I lied: when I said "original code" I actually meant "original with `Int`".

Comment: Do you mean "the original code with some type signature(s) that force everything to be `Int`"? Then the point about the lists still applies, llvm wasn't made for that, so it's not particularly good at transforming list code into loops. The `vector` package is, though, if you do your "listish" code right.

Comment: Oops, I read too fast, and only noticed the part about `Integer` vs `Int`. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome!  So now...how to make the C code perform as fast as the Haskell? :)

Comment: That's easy (in this case), @lobsterism, give it the same treatment as the Haskell, `clang -O3 original.c && time ./a.out` ;) [In other words, llvm is better at optimising loops than gcc. (For the values of llvm and gcc installed on my system)]

Comment: So the lessons learned are--hand-write your own recursive functions rather than using function composition, specify Int, and use LLVM when the code is performance critical?  Anything else?

Comment: Hand-writing the loops is not always necessary, you can often use a fusion framework like `vector`'s to achieve the same. Which is easier and/or gives better performance depends on what you're used to (I rarely use `Vector`s, I'm used to writing loops, so I usually find that easier, if you're used to using `Vector`s, you'll find that easier), and the structure of the computation (you can always fiddle with hand-written loops to try to squeeze out more, but if you let the fusion framework write the loops, you're tied to what has been done before, but it's not easy to beat a good framework).

Comment: Where they can be used, `Int` and `Word` give the best performance, so use them where possible and speed matters. Strictness and laziness are important. Where an argument needs to be evaluated anyway, make it strict, where you can start producing the result without, keep it lazy. GHC doesn't do many low-level optimisations yet, so be aware of bit-twiddling tricks to substitute other operations (division, primarily). Avoid `div` and `mod` where `quot` and `rem` will do the right thing. Whether LLVM beats the native code generator depends, but it's rare that the NCG is significantly faster.

Comment: Your answer made me happy initially, but now after a bit of time to digest, shouldn't the compiler not be able to make that optimization for me?  After all, I can see it heuristically almost *immediately*, and I'm sure these kinds of patterns occur all the time in Haskell.  Is there something preventing such compiler optimizations from being implemented?

Comment: The big hindrance in getting more optimisations is manpower. There are only a handful of people working on GHC, and they have lots of other things to do. And it's not so easy to make the optimisations general. For the ``i `mod` 4``, you have the problem that you can only replace it with `i .&. 3` if `i` is non-negative, or if you know that you're on a two's complement machine, for `rem`, only if you know `i` is non-negative. Doable, of course, but not a ten-minute-job. Eliminating the list is also not as easy for a compiler (must be general) as for the programmer (specific to the situation).

Comment: @tibbe I haven't yet learned that those are now available via `Data.Bits`, thanks. So what I had tried was `lshift (I# n) (I# s) = I# (n `uncheckedIShiftL#` s)`. Didn't make any measurable difference in execution time, nor does `unsafeShiftL`. A bit surprising, since in the core, the comparison of the shift distance against 64 is done with plain `shiftL` (but not the comparison against 0, seems GHC knows `i .&. 3` is never negative).

Comment: @DanielFischer I've verified that `shiftL` and `unsafeShiftL` produce different Core. The former has an extra branch that compares against the word size (32 in my case). It doesn't seem to matter though, likely due to the branch taken always ends up being the same and thus can be predicted reliably (and thus be free). It's still a good practice to use `unsafeShiftL` if you know that the shift amount is smaller than the word size.

Answer (score 15):

Few things beat a hand-written loop with a strict accumulator:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Data.Bits

f :: Int -> Int
f n = g 0 0
  where g !i !s | i <= n    = g (i+1) (if i .&. (unsafeShiftL 1 (i `rem` 4)) /= 0 then s+1 else s)
                | otherwise = s

main = print $ f 123456789
```

In addition to the tricks mentioned so far, this also replaces `shift` with `unsafeShiftL`, which doesn't check its argument.

Compiled with `-O2` and `-fllvm`, this is about 13x faster than the original on my machine.

<sub>**Note:** Testing if bit `i` of `x` is set can be written more clearly as `` x `testBit` i ``. This produces the same assembly as the above.</sub>

Answer (score 12):

### Vector instead of list, fold instead of filter-and-length

Substituting the list for an [unboxed vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.10/doc/html/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html) and the filter-and-length for a fold (i.e. incrementing a counter) improves the time significantly for me. Here's what I used:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as UV
import Data.Bits

foo :: Int
foo = UV.foldl (\s i -> if i .&. (shift 1 (i `rem` 4)) /= 0 then s+1 else s) 0 (UV.enumFromN 0 123456789)

main = print foo
```

The original code (with two changes though: `rem` instead of `mod` as suggested in the comments, and adding an `Int` to the signature to avoid `Integer`) gave:

```
$ time ./orig 
30864196

real    0m2.159s
user    0m2.144s
sys     0m0.008s
```

The modified code above gave:

```
$ time ./new 
30864196

real    0m1.450s
user    0m1.440s
sys     0m0.004s
```

### LLVM

While LLVM didn't have a massive effect on the original code, it really did on the modified (I'd love to learn why...).

Original (LLVM):

```
$ time ./orig-llvm 
30864196

real    0m2.047s
user    0m2.036s
sys     0m0.008s
```

Modified (LLVM):

```
$ time ./new-llvm 
30864196

real    0m0.233s
user    0m0.228s
sys     0m0.004s
```

For comparison, OP's original C code comes in at 0m0.152s user on my system.

This is all GHC 7.4.1, GCC 4.6.3, and vector 0.9.1. LLVM is either 2.9 or 3.0; I have both but can't seem to figure out which one GHC is actually using.

Comment: I'll add as an aside that *only* replacing the filter-and-length with a fold (i.e. keeping lists and not using vectors) actually gives me slightly *worse* performance than the original code when *not* using LLVM: ca. 2.6s. With LLVM I get ca. 1.4s, which is about the same improvement as going to vectors without using LLVM.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import Data.Bits
main = do
    print $ length $ filter (\i -> i .&. (shift 1 (i `rem` 4)) /= 0) [0..123456789::Int]
```

Without the `::Int`, the type defaults to `::Integer`.
`rem` does the same as `mod` on positive values, and it is the same as `%` in C. `mod` on the other hand ist mathematically correct on negative values, but is slower.

- `int` in C is 32bit
- `Int` in Haskell is either 32 or 64bit wide, like `long` in C
- `Integer` is an arbitrary-bit-integer, it has no min/max values, and its memory size depends on its value (similar to a string).