# Python remainder operator

Tags: python, modulo, integer-division

Is there any remainder operator in Python? I do not ask for modulo operator, but remainder. For example:

```
-5 mod 2 = 1
```

but

```
-5 rem 2 = -1 # where "rem" is a remainder operator.
```

Do I have to implement it by myself ;)?

Comment: Yes, you have to implement it yourself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the division remainder of a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584586/find-the-division-remainder-of-a-number)

Comment: @katrielalex but programming is hard :(

Comment: Do you really just want a truncated-division remainder, without having truncated division as well?

Comment: "I do not ask for modulo operator, but remainder." You do understand those are the same things? See Wikipedia: "In computing, the modulo (sometimes called modulus) operation finds the remainder of division of one number by another." (Or do you just want different rules about negatives?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339719/when-is-the-difference-between-quotrem-and-divmod-useful

Comment: @alecxe: This is not a dup. The OP here already knows how to get the floor-to-neg-inf remainder in Python, and wants to know how to get the truncate-to-0 remainder instead. So, a question whose answer is the `%` operator isn't very helpful.

Comment: @Thanatos Ok, I'm more familiar with C++ and I would like to have remainder operator like in C++ language ;). Where -7 % 4 is equal -3. In Python it would be 1.

Comment: @Dejwi: Actually, C++ leaves it up to the implementation to use any of the three remainder algorithms for `%`. (C99 did finally specify one, and I believe C++11 inherits that choice by incorporation of the relevant part of the C99 spec… but earlier versions of C++ definitely do not.) So, unless you've learned C++ very recently, if you've been relying on `-7 % 4 == -3`, your code wasn't portable.

Comment: @abarnert I'm pretty sure, that this is how it works on GCC na MSVCP. Thank you, I didn't know it is implementation specific.

Comment: @Dejwi: Well, that's exactly how you run into problems with implementation-specific stuff: you test it on GCC on one platform and MSVC on another and assume that if they agree, it's portable… (Well, maybe not you specifically, but I personally have created hard-to-track-down bugs that I had to fix 3 years after forgetting the code that way…)

Answer (score 24):

There are actually three different definitions of "modulo" or "remainder", not two:

- Truncated division remainder: sign is the same as the dividend.
- Floored division remainder: sign is the same as the divisor.
- Euclidean division remainder: sign is always positive.

Calling one of them "modulo" and another "remainder" is very confusing; all three of them are useful definitions for both terms.

Almost every language only provides one of the three (Fortran being a notable exception).* Most languages provide the one that matches the language's division operator.** Because Python uses floored division (following Knuth's argument in *The Art of Computer Programming*), it uses the matching remainder operator.

If you want either of the other, you have to write it manually. It's not very hard; [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation) shows how to implement all three.

For example:

```
def trunc_divmod(a, b):
    q = a / b
    q = -int(-q) if q<0 else int(q)
    r = a - b * q
    return q, r
```

Now, for your example:

```
>>> q, r = trunc_divmod(-5, 2)
>>> print(q, r)
-2 -1
```

---

* Often languages that provide both call truncated remainder some variation on `mod`, and floored some variation on `rem`… but that definitely isn't something to rely on. For example, Fortran calls floored remainder `modulo`, while Scheme calls Euclidean remainder `mod`.

** Two notable exceptions are C90 and C++03, which leave the choice up to the implementation. While many implementations use truncated division and remainder, some do not (a few even use truncated division and floored remainder, which means `a = b * (a/b) + a%b` does not even work…).

Answer (score 1):

Edit: it's not entirely clear what you meant when you were asking for a remainder operation, the way to do this will depend on what requirements there are on the sign of the output.

If the sign is to be always positive `divmod` can do what you want, it's in the standard library

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod

Also you might want to look at the built-in binary arithmetic operators:

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html

If the remainder has to have the same sign as the the argument passed then you'd have to roll your own such as this:

```
import math
def rem(x,y):
    res = x % y
    return math.copysign(res,x)
```

Comment: No, `divmod(a, b)` returns the exact same thing as `(a/b, a%b)`. In other words, the OP will still get `1` rather than `-1` as he wants.

Comment: Clearly "if the sign is to be always positive" doesn't help, because it's not true of the only example the OP gives us, `-5 rem 2 = -1`.

Comment: The new version is completely broken—try it with `rem(-5, -2)`.

Comment: This post needs correction still. "If the sign is to be always positive divmod can do [it]" is incorrect. The sign of the remainder is the same as the sign of the divisor.

Answer (score 0):

Does `math.fmod` do what you're looking for?

Comment: No, `fmod` returns the result "as defined by the platform C library". Which type of remainder that means is implementation-dependent. (C99 _does_ define one, but at least Python 2.7 is written in C90, not C99.) So, this _may_ do what he's looking for on his platform… and then do something different on another platform. (There's also the fact that `fmod` converts everything to `float`, and the docs explicitly say that it's not preferred when working with integers.)