# How do I make an if... else construct that reacts at a certain multiple of a number?

Tags: c, loops

I have an infinite loop, and would like to add an if...else loop that triggers when the loop is at the 10th, 20th, 30th, (aka a multiple of 10) time.

I'd like to know whether it's possible to make something like

```
if (x is the multiple of 10) printf(something)

else printf(something else)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python remainder operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499458/python-remainder-operator)

Comment: If it's an infinite loop, when an (unsigned) counter wraps you'll get a discontinuity. Just count to 10 and reset the counter.

Answer (score 1):

A number is a multiple of 10 if its remainder when dividing by 10 is 0.  So use the modulus operator `%`:

```
if (x % 10 == 0) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```