# Why does mod give a different result in an expression than in a function call?

Tags: haskell, modulo

Say one wants to calculate the function:

```
f (x,y) = ((x `mod` 3)+(y `mod` 3)) `mod` 2
```

Then, if one expands `f (-1,0)` manually, one gets:

```
((-1 `mod` 3)+(0 `mod` 3)) `mod` 2
1
```

If one however uses an inline function, the result is:

```
let f (x,y) = ((x `mod` 3)+(y `mod` 3)) `mod` 2 in f (-1,0)
0
```

What happens when storing the function that yields not the expected result?

I assume this is because `f` uses `Integral` instead of `Int`?

Comment: BTW (and indeed closely related to the problem): you don't need all those parens; `mod` binds automatically more tightly (`infixl 7 mod` vs `infixl 6 +`). You'd be fine with ``((-1)`mod`3 + 0`mod`3) `mod` 2``.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: True, the brackets were added in order to track down the problem :(.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like it's a matter of parsing. `` -1 `mod` 3 `` gets parsed as `` -(1 `mod` 3) `` and not `` (-1) `mod` 3 ``.

```
*Main> -(1 `mod` 3)
-1
*Main> (-1) `mod` 3
2
```

Honestly, the way unary `-` works in Haskell is a bit of a hack that I personally find confusing. If I really need a negative literal, I usually just add the extra parentheses to be sure.

Another thing to consider is that Haskell has *two* modulo functions, `mod` and `rem`, that treat negative numbers differently. For more details, look to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111120/integral-operators-quot-vs-div/8111203#8111203) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339719/when-is-the-difference-between-quotrem-and-divmod-useful/339823#339823) other questions.

Comment: This is rather strange, given the documentation [here](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/mod_f.html) seems to suggest experiments are done with negative numerators.

Comment: @CommuSoft yeah that page is kind of lame.

Comment: In most programming languages, the unary minus binds probably the most to variable, of course now it's too late. But perhaps they better had given the minus more priority.

Comment: Another point in case for `-XNegativeLiterals`, that extension fixes the issue.

Comment: @CommuSoft I argued for prefix - having a different precedence when Haskell was designed, but I was overruled.

Comment: @augustss: What was the rationale of the overruler?

Comment: @CommuSoft The rationale was that `-x` is a shorthand for `0-x` so having both versions of `-` have the same precedence was natural.  I don't agree.