# In what cases does NegativeLiterals change behavior?

Tags: haskell, language-extension

While describing the NegativeLiterals [School of Haskell](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/basic-syntax-extensions) shows an example of how using the language extension might change the performance of some code and then says

> Other examples might actually change behavior rather than simply be less efficient

After fooling around with the extension a bit I was not able to find any of these instances of behavior changes.  I was only able to find the performance changes they were talking about and a few programs that will error with and without the extension.

What are these programs that change their behavior when the NegativeLiterals extension is enabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference of negative literals is the difference of if we negate the integer then call `fromInteger` or call `fromInteger` then negate the type of the codomain.  That is, `fromInteger . negate` is not the same as `negate . fromInteger`.  I would expect this to happen when you are on the bounds of some type - one might saturate while another wraps.

For example I have a pretty trivially bad type:

```
data Bad = Bad Integer
    deriving (Show)

instance Num Bad where
    negate (Bad a) = Bad (a + 1)
    fromInteger = Bad
```

And the result:

```
*Main> (-1) :: Bad
Bad 2
*Main> :set -XNegativeLiterals
*Main> (-1) :: Bad
Bad (-1)
*Main>
```

Answer (score 2):

`NegativeLiterals` also changes how some expressions are parsed. Unary `-` is interpreted as an operator with the same precedence as binary `-` (i.e. 6), but with `NegativeLiterals` a `-` that is directly (without whitespace) followed by a number will be part of the literal. Here is an example of how this can make a difference:

```
>>> :set -XNoNegativeLiterals
>>> -1 `mod` 2
-1
>>> :set -XNegativeLiterals
>>> -1 `mod` 2
1
>>> - 1 `mod` 2
-1
```

I have got this from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25901994/why-does-mod-give-a-different-result-in-an-expression-than-in-a-function-call) StackOverflow question.

Comment: Thanks! This is a really neat example.  I would suggest adding the output for `- 1 \`mod\` 2`  with `-XNoNegativeLiterals` as well for clarity.

Comment: I do not think it would be helpful. To me including it would seem to suggest that they are different expressions with the same value but they are actually the exact same expression. Only in the case of `-XNegativeLiterals` are they parsed differently.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a fixed-size type, such as `Int8` from `Data.Int`. This is a signed integer stored in `8` bits. Its possible values range from -128 to 127. So, with the default syntax, the literal `-128` will try to store `128` in an `Int8` and then negate it, which results in overflow. With `NegativeLiterals`, it will directly construct `-128` as an `Int8`, avoiding this possible error.

---

As it turns out, on `ghci`, the literal `128` procures a warning and then produces `-128` as a result of the overflow, so as it happens `-128` produces the correct value. However, I don't believe this behavior is standardized since `Int8` is a signed type, so it's best not to rely on overflow behaving in this way.

Comment: This is exactly the case presented in the linked post so I would hope that the OP is aware of it.

Comment: Oops! I got it from [the GHC docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#negative-literals), which is probably where SoH got it too.