# Decide(in Haskell) if a number is or not a palindrome without using lists

Tags: list, haskell, palindrome, declarative

I need to check in Haskell if a four digit number is a palindrome, the problem is that I can't use lists, and in spite of having a fixed digit number, I should use recursion. I have been think on the problem  and I couldn't get a solution using recursion. The closest that I could get was this:

```
pldrm :: Integer -> Bool
pldrm x
    |x > 9999 = False
    |x > 999 = (div x 1000 == mod x 10) && (mod (div x 100) 10) == div (mod x 100) 10
    |otherwise = False
```

Do you have any idea? thanks

Comment: Compute first and last digit, check them for equality, remove them, and recurse. Should be doable with artihmetic & logical operations, only.

Comment: This is like telling a Lisp programmer not to use lists. I don't think that there is anything worth learning in it.

Comment: @Vektorweg ... oh there is ... ;)

Comment: Vektorweg: just use another Monoid!

Comment: @CarstenKönig @rampion There could be a `Traversable` instance of the number, i guess. Then just compare the backward traversed number with the regular traversed number.

Comment: @Vektorweg my guess: if Ivan is not allowed to do it using list than maybe this approach would be over the top too ;) - but you can add it to the answers for future references - I will gladly upvote

Comment: Vektorweg: Yeah, I've been looking at [`mono-traversable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable) for that reason.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about just checking if a number is equal to its reversal?

```
palindrome :: Integer -> Bool
palindrome x = reversal x == x

reversal :: Integral a => a -> a
reversal = go 0
  where go a 0 = a
        go a b = let (q,r) = b `quotRem` 10 in go (a*10 + r) q
```

This lets negative numbers like `-121` be palindromes, which is easy to check for if you don't want that to be true.

```
nonNegativePalindrome x = x >= 0 && palindrome x
```

`reversal` gives us the integer with digits in reverse order of our input (ignoring the infinite leading zeroes implicit in `12 == ...000012`).

`reversal` works by peeling off the digits from the bottom (using `quotRem`, [which is a lot like `divMod`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339719/when-is-the-difference-between-quotrem-and-divmod-useful)) and putting them together in reverse order (via muliplication and adding).

```
reversal 12345
= go 0 12345 
= go 5  1234
= go 54  123
= go 543  12
= go 5432  1
= go 54321 0
= 54321
```

It's worth noting that `n == reversal $ reversal n` only if `n` is zero or has a non-zero 1s digit. (`reversal (reversal 1200) == 12`), but that integers in the range of `reversal` are all invertible: `reversal x == reversal (reversal (reversal x))` forall `x`.

More thorough explanation of how to reach this solution [in this blog post](https://gist.github.com/rampion/a24f783b75b16f1fe57a).

Comment: +1 - really nice answer! I think you should explain it a bit more (I think the algorithm is not that easy to see) and then the OP should switch the accepted answer to this!

Answer (score 7):

Ok, this is indeed a bit tricky and more math than Haskell so let's look at a possible solution (assuming a decimal system).

The idea is to use `div` and `mod` to get at the highest and lowest digit of a number.
Remember that you can write

```
(q,r) = n `divMod` m
```

to get numbers `q` and `r` so that `q * m + r = n` with `0 <= r < q`. For `m = 10` this 
will conveniently get (for positive `n`):

- in `q` all but the last digits
- in `r` the last digit

**remark**: I had this wrong for some time - I hope it's correct now - the edge cases are really tricky.

```
palindrome :: Integer -> Bool
palindrome n = palin n (digits n)
  where
    palin x dgts
      | x < 0     = False
      | x == 0    = True
      | x < 10    = dgts == 1
      | otherwise = q == x `mod` 10 && palin inner (dgts-2)
      where
        inner = r `div` 10
        (q,r) = x `divMod` size
        size  = 10^(dgts-1)

digits :: Integer -> Integer
digits x
  | x < 10    = 1
  | otherwise = 1 + digits (x `div` 10)
```

Obvious I did not know the size of your problem so `digits` will look for the number of digits:

- digits 5445 = 4
- digits 123  = 3
- ...

The edge cases are these:

```
  | x < 0     = False
  | x == 0    = True
  | x < 10    = digits == 1
```

- Obvious negative numbers should not be palindromes
- if all digits are 0 then it's an palindrome
- one-digit numbers are palindromes if indeed we are looking only at length 1 (this had me bad, as the `inner` of stuff like `1011` is a one digit nubmer `1`)

The rest is based on this observations:

- `x div 10^(digits-1)` = the highest digit (`5445 div 1000 = 5`)
- `x mod 10^(digits-1)` = all but the highest digit (`5445 mod 1000 = 445`)
- `x mod 10`            = the lowest digit (`5445 mod 10 = 5`)
- `number div 10`       = remove the lowest digit (`5445 div 10 = 544`)

#### just to be safe let's test it using Quickcheck:

Let's use Quickcheck to test it (should be a nice example :D )

```
module Palindrome where

import Test.QuickCheck

main :: IO ()
main = do
  checkIt palindrome

palindrome :: Integer -> Bool
palindrome n = palin n (digits n)
  where
    palin x dgts
      | x < 0     = False
      | x == 0    = True
      | x < 10    = dgts == 1
      | otherwise = q == x `mod` 10 && palin inner (dgts-2)
      where
        inner = r `div` 10
        (q,r) = x `divMod` size
        size  = 10^(dgts-1)

digits :: Integer -> Integer
digits x
  | x < 10    = 1
  | otherwise = 1 + digits (x `div` 10)

checkIt :: (Integer -> Bool) -> IO ()
checkIt p =
  quickCheckWith more (\n -> n < 0 || p n == (reverse (show n) == show n))
  where more = stdArgs { maxSuccess = 10000, maxSize = 999999 }
```

seems ok:

```
runghc Palindrom.hs 
+++ OK, passed 10000 tests.
```

Comment: thank you, this is the perfect solution for the problem

Comment: Can't the definition of `inner` be simplified to `inner = (x \`mod\` size) \`div\` 10`?

Answer (score 6):

If only four digit numbers considered, you can recursively subtract 1001 to check if first and last digits are equal and then subtract 0110 to check if middle digits are equal.

```
pldrm :: Int -> Bool
pldrm x
  | x > 1000 = pldrm (x - 1001)
  | x > 100  = pldrm (x - 110)
  | otherwise = x == 0
```

Please note that this function will give incorrect results for numbers outside of [1000,9999] range.

Comment: This function is correct only for numbers >= 1000 and =< 9999, i.e. "four digit numbers". According to OP's problem statement it seems that this is exactly what he asks for.

Answer (score 3):

It is a pity that you cannot use lists. Here is cumbersome solution based on arithmetic operations (works only for four-digit numbers):

```
pldrm :: Int -> Bool -- no need for Integer if you work only with four
                     -- digit numbers
pldrm x = (div x 1000 == mod x 10) && (div y 10 == mod y 10)
    where y = rem x 1000 `quot` 10 -- extracts two inner digits
```

```
> pldrm 3113
True
> pldrm 3111
False
```

Comment: @WillNess, indeed! I've improved this mess a little bit :-)

Comment: great; just one more thing, :) `f x | b = True | otherwise = False` is more idiomatically written `f x = b`.

Comment: @WillNess, oh yeah! Although I have to remove the first guard too in this case. Anyway, it looks like a decent solution now! Thanks!

Comment: not necessarily, no. you could have `f x | t = error | otherwise = b`. :) and you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
isPolindrom :: Integer -> Bool 
isPolindrom n = if let i = read (reverse (show n)) :: Integer in i==n then True else False
```

Comment: Hi @Seliverstov. Thank you for your answer. Although the code it's fine and simple, it's a good practice adding some explanation about it

Comment: `if a 
      then True 
      else False` is the same as `a`. `show` produces a *list*, and `reverse` reverses a *list*, which seems to contradict the requirement in the question.